# AWS API Gateway file upload fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a .NET Core website and a .NET Core Web API. On the website you can upload an image file which then gets posted to the API. The API then uploads this image to AWS S3 for storage.

The website is hosted on an EC2 instance with IIS and the API is an AWS Serverless Lambda application (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/lambda-build-test-severless-app.html)

This is working, however I am encountering issues when the file size is large. For example, a 1 MB image will upload without any problems but a 5MB file will fail, seemingly before it even reaches the API code. I say this because I have logging on the first line of my Controller method and nothing is logged for the larger file. I am unable to provide much more information unfortunately because this is only happening in the live environment, when I run locally it works fine, regardless of file size.

I know the payload size limit for API Gateway is 10MB as shown here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html. Also, the default timeout for API Gateway requests is 29000ms and it does not hang for nearly that long when I try to upload an image so I don't think it's hitting this timeout.

[image]

Comment: You should check your logs to see what part of the stack are or are not being invoked. I'd start with Lambda, as I suspect your hitting the synchronous invocation payload limit of 6MB there. If you are sending a binary file, remember that API Gateway will convert that to a base64 file when forwarding to Lambda, and that will increase the size of the file by approx. a third.

Comment: Ahh, I was not aware of this limit. I think I will just add a size limit of around 2MB to avoid this in future. Thank you very much for your help.